# Mutate numerical column name with respect to another variable R

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, tibble

I have a tibble with the following structure:

[image: actual tibble]

In that tibble there are a vast amount of lines, the ids are unique and for each one of them there is at least one value different from NA (in the column whose name coincides with the value in the variable min_date).

What I would like to do is to complete the information of the numerical named columns such that every NA that appears after a column with a value is replaced with the last value that has been shown.
The following image shows how I wold like to have my result:

[image: expected output]

The way I solve it must be independent of the years that are shown.

I tried to gather the numerical named columns in order to have a tibble with more rows and a variable with all those dates, after that I used a for loop grouping by the ids and filling the spaces the way I wanted. I took a small sample of my tibble and verified that it worked, but it could not be done for all the data.

I believe that happens because I have aproximately 20.000.000 of rows and more or less 4.000.000 of ids.
Thats why after trying with the for loop I chose to use the spreaded data and then to try to solve it that way, but I was not able to call the new numerical named columns in a correct way in order to replace them using the function mutate.

I would like to know if there is a different and more efficient way to do it. I use tidyverse, but if there is a different package to use i will check that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Yesid Sánchez Arias! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: Please do as r2evans suggested. That said, I would use `dplyr::pivot_longer` followed by `tidyr::fill(direction = "down")`, then `dplyr::pivot_wider`.

Comment: Thaks a lot for giving me this information about how the question should be written, I will use it for future questions or coments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of data, I tend to prefer to pivot it so that the column names (which are *years*, aka "data" of some form).

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, min_date), names_to = "year") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 25 × 4
#    id    min_date year  value
#    <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#  1 id1       2021 2018     NA
#  2 id1       2021 2019     NA
#  3 id1       2021 2020     NA
#  4 id1       2021 2021     12
#  5 id1       2021 2022     45
#  6 id2       2018 2018     56
#  7 id2       2018 2019     56
#  8 id2       2018 2020     34
#  9 id2       2018 2021     34
# 10 id2       2018 2022     34
# # … with 15 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

but if you *really* must have it in a wider format, you can then re-pivot wider:

```r
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id, min_date), names_to = "year") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = value) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   id    min_date `2018` `2019` `2020` `2021` `2022`
#   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 id1       2021     NA     NA     NA     12     45
# 2 id2       2018     56     56     34     34     34
# 3 id3       2021     NA     NA     NA    976    976
# 4 id4       2019     NA     86     86     97     97
# 5 id5       2018    125    445    453    453     34
```

## base R

Assuming you prefer to keep it *wide*,

```r
dat[,3:7] <- t(apply(dat[,3:7], 1, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
dat
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   id    min_date `2018` `2019` `2020` `2021` `2022`
#   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 id1       2021     NA     NA     NA     12     45
# 2 id2       2018     56     56     34     34     34
# 3 id3       2021     NA     NA     NA    976    976
# 4 id4       2019     NA     86     86     97     97
# 5 id5       2018    125    445    453    453     34
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- tibble(id=paste0("id", 1:5), min_date=c(2021,2018,2021,2019,2018), `2018`=c(NA,56,NA,NA,125), `2019`=c(NA,NA,NA,86,445), `2020`=c(NA,34,NA,NA,453), `2021`=c(12,NA,976,97,NA), `2022`=c(45,NA,NA,NA,34))
```